# Changing content of a div with Prototype or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VCskB/) code :

```
<div class="box_container">
    <div class="box_container_button" id="navigator_1">
        Button 1
    </div>

    <div class="box_container_button" id="navigator_2">
        Button 2
    </div>

    <div class="box_container_button" id="navigator_3">
        Button 3
    </div>

    <div class="box_container_content" style="background-color:#d5d5d5;" id="navigator_content_1">
        Content 1               
    </div> 

    <div class="box_container_content" style="background-color:#00aeef; display:none;" id="navigator_content_2">
        Content 2              
    </div>

    <div class="box_container_content" style="background-color:#4db848; display:none;" id="navigator_content_3">
        Content 3               
    </div>               
</div>
```

If I press on the button with navigator_2, navigator_content_1 must be hidden, and navigator_content_2 showed.

How can I do this with prototype? (Or javascript if it's too stronger). Unfortunatly I can't use jQuery.

Comment: Prototype.js *is* JavaScript.

Comment: I know, as jQuery, but it's faster/easy/cross-browser to use this frameworks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function nav(obj)
{
    document.getElementById("navigator_content_1").style.display = "hidden"
    document.getElementById("navigator_content_2").style.display = "hidden"
    document.getElementById("navigator_content_3").style.display = "hidden"

    obj.style.display = "none";
}
```

Add `onclick="nav(this)"` to each button element.

Comment: Anyway, it works with style.display = "none" ;) Maybe you would to edit your answer

Comment: The use of the onclick attribute is discouraged especially if you use a js framework

Comment: You are not but markzzz is (as he said), btw the reason is well explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704479/stoppropagation-element-addeventlistener-vs-onclick-attribute Thank you for your unexplained/vegenance  -1

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Give the container holding the buttons in ID (for convenience).
2. Change the IDs of the content containers from `navigator_content_1` to `navigator_1_content` (again, for convenience).

Then all you have to do is to keep a reference to the currently showed content pane and you have to attach a click handler to the container holding the buttons:

```
// by default, the first panel is shown
var current = document.getElementById('navigator_1_content');

document.getElementById('box_container').onclick = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;  // for IE
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // for IE

    current.style.display = 'none';
    current = document.getElementById(target.id + '_content');
    current.style.display = 'block';          
};
```

This makes use of [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). [`event.target`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target) has a reference to the element that was actually clicked (I don't know if the Safari bug is still present, you might have to traverse the DOM up to find the correct element). This can certainly be improved but should give you a good start. You can easily add new buttons / content panels without having to modify the code.

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/VCskB/5/).

To learn more about event handling, I suggest to have a look at the [excellent articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Answer (score -1):

This would use prototype and get what you want

```
$$('.box_container_button').each(function(element) {
    element.observe('click', function(event) {
        $$('.box_container_content').each(function(element) {
            element.setStyle({
                'display': 'none'
            });
        });
        $('navigator_content_' + this.id.replace("navigator_", "")).setStyle({
            'display': 'block'
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VENLh/

**THIS** solution would work even if you add more buttons / contents without changing any line in the javascript (just add the html part!)

Comment: So when you give a -1 you get a -1 ? pillow fight ? -.- give me a good reason.